# How do I throw error in one function to be caught by another function?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

I have this "test" code:

```
function func1(){
    try{
    ...stuff...
    }catch(err){
        throw new Error();
    }
}

function func2(){
    try{
        func1();
    }catch(err){
        console.log("ERROR")
    }
}

func2();
```

I have a function that throws an error in the catch in a try-catch-statement. I want it to, if func1 throws Error, it gets caught by the first try-catch-statement, but when I try this, it doesn't get caught by the first statement, it just pauses the code and returns the error. What have I done wrong? and is this the wrong way to do it?

Comment: What is it that you need exactly?

Comment: It's not clear from your description what you are trying to do and what isn't working - can you give more detail, perhaps with a runnable example? But the code you have there should (assuming an error is thrown by `...stuff...`) catch the error first in `func1`, raise a new error and then catch it in `func2`.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt func1 is handling some action that might return an error, in that case, I need it to go back to func2 (the function that called func1) and perform some other actions.

Comment: If that is the case, why use a individual try/catch for func1? since you are executing the func1 in the try block of func2, if error occurs, it will naturally go to catch block of func2 right?

Answer (score 6):

This code should give you an idea of how `try/catch` blocks work. In the first function call, we call `func2` which has a `try/catch` block. You can see in the console that the error is caught and execution continues. Then we call `func1` which throws an uncaught error, which shows up in the console as an error.

```js
function func1() {
  console.log('func1...');
  throw new Error('something bad happened!');
}

function func2() {
  console.log('func2...');
  try {
    func1();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Caught error');
  }
}

console.log('func2()');
func2();

console.log('func1()');
func1();
```

Comment: This really helped me. It was so hard to find an answer to why errors were not catched in the parent function. I was returning, now throwing. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for a separate try/catch block in `func1` because, it is already within the error handler of `func2`. In this case, whatever error you throw from `func1` will automatically caught by `func2`

```js
function func1() {
    throw new Error('oops');
}

function func2() {
  try {
    func1();
  } catch(err) {
    alert(err.message);
  }
}
    
func2();
```

Comment: I came across this in a project where a runtime error in one part of the code got handled by a try/catch in a different part of the code that I interpreted as not related to the code where the error occurred. But seeing this explanation I realise that the code just got handled at a higher level in the call chain..

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly where you are stuck but this should work:

*Make sure you check your real console*

```js
function func1() {
  try {
    throw new Error('hi from func1')
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}

function func2() {
  try {
    func1();
  } catch (err) {
    // this doesn't work in stack snippets console
    // hit f12 to see your real console
    console.log('catched in func2', err)
  }
}

func2();
```

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing, but instead of func2 catching the error, it stops the code.

Comment: It throws a normal error, like if there wasn't another try-catch-statement.

Comment: Again what kind of error was thrown? some errors will always shown in console. provide an example, we can't guess your code :)

Comment: @Sagivb.g i am having a similar code just like the one you wrote, i have used "throw err" in the first function and also logged the error, but when i log the same error in the func2 it throws undefined error..could you please help me here..